# Package bash script in "executable" for double-click execution (ideally platform independent)?

Tags: bash, package, executable, platypus

I wrote a number of bash scripts that greatly simplify the routine, but very tedious, file manipulation that my group does.

Unfortunately, most in my group cannot open a terminal, let alone run scripts with complex arguments.

Is there a way to nicely package a bash script into an executable (that accepts arguments) that runs nicely on multiple computer platforms?

I run Mac OS X, but many of my colleagues run Windows (which can run bash scripts via Cygwin, etc.). I am aware of Platypus, but is there an equivalent for Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if it meets all of your requirements but I use [makeself](http://megastep.org/makeself/) wich is really great to package things. It works with cygwin, so it might fill in your needs ^^

Basically, when you create a makeself archive, you give a script that will be executed when the archive is "launched". This script get all the parameters given to the archive (whatever you want) :

```
makeself.sh ${dir_to_archive} ${name_of_archive} ${description} ${startup_script}
```

When you run the auto-extractible archive, you do :

```
my_archive.run ${param1} ${param2} ${paramN}
```

It will uncompress your archive and run :

```
${startup_script} ${param1} ${param2} ${paramN}
```

my2c

Comment: This looks very close to what I want, but can it accept an argument (like a path) to perform an action when the end-user double-clicks on it? Thanks.

Comment: @penyuan: I've added an example. Yes it can accept arguments.